# Авто генерация полученных данных из сервиса для теста/заглушки

Tags: c#, .net

1)Есть объект, для примера:

```
public class PersonalData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // ... очень много полей в т.ч. вложенные
}
```

2)Получаем данные из http запроса, парсинга, стороннего ресурса и т.д. Естественно эти данные можно посмотреть в дебаге. Нужно эти данные получить в виде строки.

3)Хочу в итоге получить:

```
    var pd = new PersonalData();
    pd.FirstName = "name";
    pd.MiddleName = "secondname";
    pd.LastName = "surname";
    // и еще много, много данных
```

Чтобы потом можно copy-paste сделать в нужное место в коде.

Comment: [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture)?

Comment: AutoFixture - автоматически генерирует данные. Мне же нужно получить реально существующие данные. Например в дебаге copy-paste-ом. Пока на ум приходит вставлять в ToString скрипт, который через рефлексию генерирует объект, может кто то уже делал такое или придумал лучше...

Comment: Как связаны _реально существующие данные_ и мок? Может, вам AutoMapper нужен?

Comment: Вы правы, мок не совсем корректно называть поправил. AutoMapper нет, речь идет об автогенерации. Неужели не у кого не возникало желания при дебаге, закопипастить эти данные и сделать тест.

Comment: Может, вы про серилизацию говорите? Например, в json? Сериализуете ваши запросы в файлик, а в тестах десериализуете

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ. Инструмент называется [Object Exporter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarElabd.ObjectExporter)

[Описание его.](http://www.omarelabd.net/exporting-objects-from-the-visual-studio-debugger/)